# Issues with compiling a Keras sequential model

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision, classification, conv-neural-network

I came across the following error while compiling a Keras Sequential model:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 45985 arrays: [array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
   ...
```

This is the code and the data format I am using for X_train, y_train, X_test and y_test:

```
print(X_train.shape)

>>(45985, 50, 50, 3)

print(X_test.shape)

>>(22650, 50, 50, 3)

print(y_train[0])

>>array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", input_shape=(50,50,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=3)
```

Comment: What is the dtype (X_train.dtype) of each of your arrays?

Comment: X_train.dtype---> dtype('float64')

Comment: Your input shape is (45985, 50, 50, 3) of xtrain while the input to keras is 50,50,3 which is the cause of error

Comment: @JaskaranSingh I am not sure how exactly to change the code in this case. Do you mind clarifying?

Comment: @JaskaranSingh No, that's wrong, the error points to the targets.

Comment: Yours xtrain contains 45985 items of 50 50 3 of data. You need to reshape it.  @Matias your are correct my mistake

Answer (score 2):

Your `y_train` as a list of numpy arrays, it should be a single numpy array with shape `(samples, 10)`. You can transform it with:

```
y_train = np.array(y_train, dtype=np.float32)
```

Then you should remember to one-hot encode your labels (they look like integer labels):

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical

y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
```

Comment: My y_train was already one hot encoded and now I get the following error: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_27 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (24,)

Comment: @EwaSzyszka Sounds like you have 24 classes instead of 10, the model expects 10 classes, you should change the last Dense to Dense(24, activation="softmax")

Comment: Changing the list to np array solved the issue: y_train = np.asarray(y_train)
y_test = np.asarray(y_test)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to one-hot encoding the labels mentioned in the other answer, you can keep your labels as they are, i.e. sparse/integer labels, and use `'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` as the loss function instead. This would help with saving memory, especially if you have lots of samples and/or classes. Though, don't forget that anyways you need to convert your labels to numpy array.